# Configuring ESLint with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I have the following directory structure:

```
/
├──.node-modules
├──server             # server code
│   ├──...
├──shared             # modules used by client and server
├──webapp             # client code
│   ├──...
│   ├──eslintrc.js    # client eslint config
├──eslintrc.js        # project eslint config
└──webpack.config.js
```

I use Vue for client code and `dbaeumer.vscode-eslint` extension for VSCode. On the `.vue` files I keep getting errors on the `import` statements.

> Unable to resolve path to module `module`

I've been messing with `eslint.workingDirectories` settings to set this up, but had no success. Inside my client local eslint config I have the import/resolver defined:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': 'webpack',
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you please share more details of your setup? Eg. Vue version, created using vue-cli, using Typecript, the kind of files you are trying to import (node module, custom .ts, .js, .vue files), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a `node` version issue. My distro only distributes the latest version of `node`. I've done the following for the errors to correct themselves.

1. Installed [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
2. Set the version of node to `10.10.0`

   ```
   $ nvm install 10.10.0
   $ nvm use 10.10.0
   ```
3. Inside the `home/user/'Code - OSS'/User/settings.json` file, added the following field to the `JSON` settings:

   ```
   {
     ...
     "eslint.runtime": "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin/node"  // This should be the path to the node runtime set by nvm
   }
   ```
4. After saving and restarting VSCode the errors were gone and ESLint is working correctly now.

NOTE: Check which version your system is using with `nvm ls` command. The output should look something like this

```
$ nvm ls
       v6.14.4
->     v10.10.0
       v10.20.0
       v12.16.2
default -> 10.10.0 (-> v10.10.0)
node -> stable (-> v12.16.2) (default)
stable -> 12.16 (-> v12.16.2) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/erbium (-> v12.16.2)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.20.0
lts/erbium -> v12.16.2
```

Thank you for the help everyone. Sorry if the question did not give more relevant details as I did not have any clue on where the problem may lay, so I asked for assistance from a good friend who's experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMrDePs86Uo)
while installing ESlint on my VS Code a while back.

Maybe it can be an issue with version, and you can check the best version that worked from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install these packages?

npm install eslint-plugin-import --save-dev

npm install eslint-plugin-node --save-dev

npm install eslint-plugin-promise --save-dev

npm install eslint-plugin-standard --save-dev